# How to install a Linux distro from within Mac OS X

Tags: linux, macos, linux-distributions, wubi

I want to install a Linux distro on my Mac from within Mac OS X (that is, without first rebooting into a separate installer environment).

Just like Ubuntu's Wubi installer allows you to install Ubuntu from within Windows, I want to install a Linux distro from within Mac OS X.

Is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no such thing for Mac OS X. The "wubi" installer is Ubuntu-specific and only available for Windows.

Your best bet is to use VirtualBox for Mac OS X to test any distro you like.

Comment: Or its competitors, VMware Fusion and Parallels.

Comment: IMO, linux integration in all three VM products is so poor that @nash might as well use VirtualBox rather than paying for something that wouldn't do much better. If it were Windows he was looking to test, I'd happily recommend Parallels, but not for Linux.